# How to show the select values after form is submited and there are errors?

Tags: jquery, laravel

When the user submit the form if there are any errors the fields should be populated with the submited values so the user dont need to insert theses values again. This is working fine but for the select field is not working.

I have the code below:

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('post.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="event_categories">Categories</span></label>
        <select required  multiple class="form-control"  name="categories[]" id="categories">

            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
```

Do you know why selected categories dont appear if there are any errors after the form is submited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify that an `<option>` should initially be selected when you load the page by giving it the appropriate attribute:

```
<option selected>...</option>
```

In the code you provided, the `selected` attribute is never applied to any of your `<option>`s, so the browser will never set them as `selected` when you load the page.

When you have been redirected back to the form, the browser doesn't know what data was submitted with the previous request (the POST request made when submitting the form), so it cannot automatically set any of the options as `selected`, unless explicitly told to in the HTML response returned by the application.

When the validation fails, Laravel automatically flashes the submitted form data onto the session, so you can retrieve it in the following request and use this information to render the form, dictating to the browser which of the `<option>`s were previously `selected` (if at all).

You can access the data submitted with the previous request  using Laravel's [`old()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-old) helper.

To get the value that was submitted for a field, pass the `name` of the field to the helper:

```
<input name="something" value="{{ old('something', 'optional fallback value') }}">
```

Since PHP interprets your field's value as an array, `old('categories')` will return an array of values or `null`.

Now for each of your options, check if the value of the current option in the loop appears in the array of old values, applying the `selected` attribute if it does:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    <option {{ in_array($category->id, old('categories', [])) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $category->id }}">
        {{ $category->name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

It is important to include the second parameter in the call to the `old()` helper which sets an empty array (`[]`) as the fallback value. This prevents it from returning `null` when it fails to find the specified key in the previous request's data, which would cause [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to throw an error.

---

Also, you have an errant closing `</span>` tag in the label:

```
<label for="event_categories">Categories</span></label>
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `selected` attribute on options:

```
<option value="{{$category->id}}" {{ in_array($category->id, old('categories')) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$category->name}}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it appears in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel documentation fo this
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input

Retrieving Old Input

To retrieve flashed input from the previous request, use the old method on the Request instance. The old method will pull the previously flashed input data from the session:

```
username = $request->old('username');
```

Laravel also provides a global old helper. If you are displaying old input within a Blade template, it is more convenient to use the old helper. If no old input exists for the given field, null will be returned:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

And what about if you use the @old as the first option in select? Before @foreach loop

Comment: It also dont works with: <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label for="categories">Categories</label>
        <select required  multiple class="form-control" value="{{old('categories')}}" name="categories[]" id="categories">

            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{ old('categories', $category->name) }}</option>
            @endforeach

        </select>
    </div>
</div>